# Executing a php script on a server without any params with HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, php, android, http

I'm trying to run a php script that doesn't need any parameters, located on a free web hosting server, with the `HttpURLConnection` class.
This is my code, within an `AsyncTask`:

```
URL url = new URL("http://**********/connect.php");
HttpURLConnection urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlconnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
urlconnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
urlconnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlconnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlconnection.connect();
// add more code here to send a run request ?
urlconnection.disconnect();
```

Should I use the `write()` method of a `OutputStream` object to send a 'run the script' request ? Shouldn't establishing a connection to the URL just be enough ?
(Note : While debugging, i do not get any exceptions, meaning the connection is made).
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Since you only need to invoke the script with no any params at all, you don't need POST method, use GET instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you do here is enough. However, to know if your script was running, you certainly need to parse server response. Minimum solution here would be checking of the response code. Try this

```
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
final String DEBUG_TAG = "DEBUG LOG";
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Response code: " + response);
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Script was running: " + (response == 200));
```

And you don't need POST method here since you don't provide any data to the script, so use GET.
Read more here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

As a side note I want to add that these days it's not recommended to use HttpURLConnection library, use Apache implementation instead or use some more advanced library like OkHttp or similar.

Comment: Thanks both for your help. It worked when i did a getResponseCode(). It doesn't work without it. I will look into the Apache implementation and OkHttp. Is Volley still used ?

Comment: AFAIK it's pretty popular.